# How to get data from multiple models and insert into single model in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 4 model classes: `flights`, `cabins`, `passengers` and, `Reservation`.

I created a form and on the basis of the form entries, I searched data from cabins and flights model.

Search form view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Flights", FormMethod.Post))
   {
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radio2" class="radio-btn" value="roundtrip" />
    
@Html.DropDownList("FromCity", ViewBag.cityList as SelectList, "From : City")
    
@Html.DropDownList("ToCity", ViewBag.cityList as SelectList, "To : City")
                              
@Html.Editor("DDate",Convert.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy"), new { htmlAttributes = new {type = "date" } })

@Html.Editor("RDate",Convert.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy"), new { htmlAttributes = new {type = "date" } })
    
@Html.Editor("SecondDDate",Convert.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy"), new { htmlAttributes = new {type = "date" } })
    
<input type="number" name="pessengers" placeholder="pessengers">
    
@Html.DropDownList("CabinsId", ViewBag.cabins as SelectList)
    
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="FlexibleDate" id="form-check" checked="checked" value="true">

<button type="submit" class="search_btn ms-lg-2">Find Flight</button>
    
    }
```

here is my controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Search(string radioBtn,string FromCity,string ToCity,string FromSecondCity,string ToSecondCity, DateTime DDate,DateTime? SecondDDate,DateTime? RDate, bool? FlexibleDate,int pessengers,int CabinsId)
    {
            ViewBag.radio = radioBtn;
            ViewBag.cabin = db.Cabins.Where(m => m.CabinsId == CabinsId).FirstOrDefault();
            ViewBag.pessengers = pessengers;
    
         if (radioBtn == "roundtrip" && FlexibleDate == null)
                {
                    List<Flights> data1 = db.Flights.Where(m => m.FromCity.Equals(FromCity) &&
                    m.ToCity.Equals(ToCity) &&
                    m.DepartureDate.Equals(DDate)).ToList();
    
                    List<Flights> data2 = db.Flights.Where(m => m.FromCity == ToCity  &&
                    m.ToCity == FromCity && m.DepartureDate == RDate).ToList();
    
                    if (data1.Count == 0)
                        ViewBag.message = "There are no flights for your departure date";
                    if (data2.Count == 0)
                        ViewBag.message = "There are no flights for your return date";
                    
                    var data = data1.Concat(data2);
    
                    return View(data);
                }
    }
```

In the above code 'data' variable contains my search result from the 'flights' model which is being passed to view. Along with this, I want to get the record from the cabin model by the 'CabinsId'.After getting these values I want to display specific columns from these two tables in a single view with a select button.

Now after clicking the select button I want to maintain these displayed values and show a separate signup form for each passenger passed to in the search action parameters.

After the user signs up I want to store the passenger information in 'passengers' models and maintained values from previous view in 'Reservation' models.

How to can I achieve this?

Comment: You just need to define a new class where you can add properties from the two models or just add a reference to the already built model instances and pass an instance of this new class to your View. Basically this is the concept of a ViewModel class

Comment: I have created a ViewModel class and  accessed it into the view but the problem is that I can only get the classes names added to the ViewModel classes not the properties of the classes.

Comment: OK, a thing to keep always in mind when you post on SO is that some lines of code are better than thousands words trying to explain the problem. I suggest you to add the relevant code in your class that builds and returns the ViewModel and then some lines from the View where you try to use that ViewModel

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I try to edit the post

Comment: @Steve I have re-organized the post.